# How do I fix this Error, Error: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

Can someone help me. Im learning how to host my react js website using firebase. Im already logged in but when i type "firebase init hosting" on the console and choose "use already existing " i get this error "Error: Failed to create project. See firebase-debug.log for more info."

I saw a video on youtube Where youll have to log in to firebase on the console, but when i used "firebase login" it says im already logged in.

Comment: What did the debug log tell you?

Comment: [debug] [2024-01-10T15:58:54.684Z] HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
[debug] [2024-01-10T15:58:55.437Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code. its a terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix the error. All i had to do was to log out of firebase from my terminal with "Firebase logout", then log back in from the terminal using "Firebase login".